# How to eval in a repl all forms in a file in Idea Cursive plugin for Clojure?

Tags: clojure, cursive

There is an "eval form hotkey", so if I manually eval each top-level form in a file I get what I want eventually. But I can't find a way to eval all forms at once. Sometimes form `a` depends on `b` which depends on `c` and manual evaluation is not convenient. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your shortcut for **Load file in REPL** in **keymap**(Preferences)